# Change syntax Html.TextBox to input in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, input, textbox

Is it possible to change this:

```
@(Html.TextBox("q", Model.Search.FreeSearc))
```

to this:

```
<input type="text"... />
```

thanks...

Comment: yes I whant it to change in View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code :-

```
<input id="q" name="FreeSearc" type="text" value = "@Model.Search.FreeSearc" />
```